# Why most of the Number prototype functions has a global duplicate function?

Tags: javascript

I really wonder, what is the purpose of having 2 duplicate functions.

For example:

> isFinite() and Number.isFinite()
>
> isNaN() and Number.isNaN()

But for example there is no `IsInteger()` function, when there is `Number.isInteger()`.

What is the difference?

Why duplicates exists?

When one should use Number prototype function or the Global function?

Comment: The MDN docs for [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) and [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) answer your questions.

Comment: Mostly… Javascript was *created* in a hurry, and only later did standardization and an actual *design* process start. Most of the headscratchers in today's Javascript are an accident of history and still exist for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Those aren't `Number.prototype` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global one is kind of the old version kept intact for backward compatibility, as pointed out by @squint and @deceze. They have visible differences like the following as the global one converts values to `Number` before testing.

```
isNaN('NaN'); //true
Number.isNaN('NaN')//false ,considers it as a string

Number.isFinite('100');//false ,considers it as a string
isFinite('100');//true
```

The purpose it not to break code written for old implementation and have a better one in place for new developers.  (same as backwards compatibility)